# How to check caller is part of AD Security group in WebAPI layer?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, authorization, azure-active-directory, adal.js

I have a website (WebApp) from where I make Ajax calls to my WebAPI layer that accepts JWT Bearer Token auth. I have integrated Adal.js into my front end script layer and the config values look like this.

```
var config = {
instance: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
tenant: "tenant.com",
clientId: "CLIENT_ID OF THE PORTAL APP", // Web-Portal app
redirectUri: "http://localhost:8241/",
popUp: true,
cacheLocation: "localStorage" };
```

The WebApiConfig looks like this:

```
var webApiConfig = {
    resourceId: "CLIENT_ID OF API APP", // Web-API app
    resourceBaseAddress: "http://localhost:9020/"
};
```

It all works fine, I am able to authenticate/authorize and call my webapi via an access token via Implicit oauth flow.

Now I would like to be able to retrieve the User's security group membership values for the logged in user so that **at the WebAPI layer**, I can make sure the user belongs to a particular security group as part of the authorization logic. So I set the GroupMembershipClaims: "SecurityGroup" in the App's manifest xml in Azure AD (I did this for the WebApi App manifest first, but then also in the WebApp app manifest).

However, looks like GroupMembershipClaims are only included in the idtoken and **not** the accessToken. And given it is the accessToken that is sent to the WebAPI, I am unable to do this check at that layer. I guess I could make the check at the WebApp layer, but given this WebApi layer will be called from many other frontend apps (which are not owned by me, I am primarily an "API provider"), that is not a secure soln.

So how do I solve this? I guess one way is to use the "on-behalf-of" flow on the WebApi layer to make calls to Graph API to find this out? I am afraid that will require more permissions than available at User scope.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good question.

My immediate first thought was "well you can get them from Graph API", but I see you already thought of that :)

If you want to do that, you can use On-behalf-of like you said, and use this operation on MS Graph API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_getmembergroups.
You would need these delegated permissions: *User.Read and Group.Read.All*.
So you would need the permission to read all groups in addition to the basic User.Read.

There are a couple other options.

You can define roles in your API.
I wrote an article on how to do this: [Defining permission scopes and roles offered by an app in Azure AD](https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad).
So if you define a role like this in the API's manifest:

```
{
  "appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "Administrator",
      "id": "179c1dc0-4801-46f3-bc0d-35f059da1415",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Administrators can access advanced features.",
      "value": "admin"
    }
  ]
}
```

You'll need to make the id a unique GUID for each role, you can use online generators or PowerShell for that `[System.Guid]::NewGuid()`.

These roles can then be assigned to users, and if you have at least Azure AD Basic, you can assign them to groups.
Roles are included in access tokens, so you can check these quite easily in your API.

The other idea I had was to have the API and front-end use the same registered app in Azure AD.
This way you could pass the Id token to the API instead of an access token, and you'd get the groups.
But since you might have other front-ends too, I doubt this would work for you.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at your blog and this seemed like a great solution for me - using Roles (of type User, at least at first) to assign specific user principals (and even AD sec groups, I suppose) to a given App Role. And verify this at my WebAPI since this will be in the Access Token. 

HOWEVER, when I tried to play with this, I found out that in order to <Add User> to an Enterprise App, I need Global Admin privileges! (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-coreapps-assign-user-azure-portal).

Seriously disappointed with that find :(

Comment: Ouch. Did not remember that one. Hopefully you can assign groups so you don't have to touch the assignments again.

Comment: And about your 2 other suggestions:
1) Accessing Graph API (from WebAPI layer) required Group.Read.All - which actually needs AD Admin Consent, which I am not sure if my org's admins will grant. (we are a mega corp)
2) Using WebAPI client_id for both the client and the WebAPI while authorizing - I briefly considered this but it is a hack and I think it could be trouble down the road.

Either way it looks like my Global Admins need to be involved here.

Comment: thanks for the fast response. So when you say "assign groups", I assume you mean I ask my global admin to add a new AD security group (that I create) into this WebAPI Enterprise App and then manage memberships into that AD group elsewhere? That could work, I was hoping not to involve the global admins (dont even know who they are; again - megacorp problems :).

Comment: Yeah, so if you have AAD Basic or any paid license, you can assign a security group into an app role. That way to give a user the role, you would only need to add them to the group. Which I think will be easier to do :)

Comment: Got my global admin involved; they suggested the same as juunas did - to add a new AppRole for User and Application and then they helped add an AD sec group (newly created) to the Enterprise Application "user and groups" list. With this setup, I have confirmed that 1) my Access Token contains the "Role" claim and 2) in my WebAPI layer, I can use attribute decorations like [Authorize(Roles="Administrator")] and it works correctly. Lot less code to write and my access is controlled via good ol AD security groups.